# How can a JS tree node retain a reference to its parent without becoming circular?

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to have a tree structure where each node can have a reference to its parent node, like so:

```
class Tree {
  constructor(name, parent = null) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = [];
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  appendChild(name) {
    this.children.push(new Tree(name, this));
  }
}

let myTree = new Tree("Sarah");
myTree.appendChild("Laura");
```

The problem is that such a structure is impossible to represent in JSON, because it's circular: Sarah contains a reference to her child Laura which contains a reference to her parent Sarah which contains a reference to her child Laura, and so on.

What I'd really like is for the child to simply have a *pointer* to its parent, that doesn't get evaluated into the full parent. But I don't think that's possible. So what should I do?

Comment: Please clarify, you are talking about JSON at some point. What does it have to do in this question? Is your goal to represent that tree in JSON and/or javascript?

Comment: Either a) Don't include the `parent` field in your JSON; or b) give your `Tree` objects an ID and use the ID instead of the object in your JSON; or c) look into [JSON Pointer](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6901).

Comment: I agree with the other comments, and I would add: think of how you will use your tree. This structure is inconsistent: you have the same information in 2 points, which can lead to an inconsistency between the list of children of A and the fact that A is identified as a parent for B. If you don't need to browse your tree down-to-top, do not include the "parent" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom *toJSON* method, which resolves the references to strings as id, then add another *fromJSON* method that does the opposite, e.g:

```
Tree.toJSON=function(tree,i=0){
  tree.lookup=i;
  tree.children.forEach(function(child){
    child.parent=i;
    Tree.toJSON(child,++this.i);
  },{i});
  if(!i) return JSON.stringify(tree);
}

Tree.fromJSON=function(tree,lookup=new Map()){
  if(typeof tree==="string")  tree=JSON.parse(tree);
  lookup.set(tree.lookup,tree);
  tree.children.forEach(function(child){
    child.parent=lookup.get(child.parent);
    Tree.fromJSON(child,lookup);
  });
  return tree;
}
```

But if were just talking about a parent reference, it might be easier to simple remove it, and add it later:

```
//toJSON
tree.children.forEach(function(child){
  delete child.parent;
});

//fromJSON
tree.children.forEach(function(child){
 child.parent=tree;
});
```